# How clear PhpStorm recently edited files list

Tags: phpstorm

This list opening in PhpStorm by <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd> ("Recent files" or "Recently changed files").

But how I can clear this history list? Is it possible in PhpStorm 9?

Answer (score 9):

Just use <kbd>Del</kbd> key in that popup window -- it will delete currently selected entry from that list.

It works with `Recent Files` (<kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>) but does not affect `Recently Edited Files` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + E</kbd>). For this one you will have to edit config file directly:

- close project in IDE/or whole IDE (otherwise IDE will overwrite those changes on exit)
- navigate to `PROJECT/.idea` folder
- open `workaspace.xml` in any plain text editor
- find and delete whole `<component name="IdeDocumentHistory">` XML node.
- save changes